# How to make SDL 2.0 work with android studio

Tags: android, sdl-2

I have downloaded the latest SDL version 2.0.4.

I went through the given project, but I could compile the SDL inside android studio.

It says `<windows.h>` not found, SDL2-2.0.4\src\core\windows\SDL_Windows.h includes header

I am not sure windows.h available for android, will it really compile? anyone succeeded?

Comment: Android Studio and gradle integration of NDK C code can be tricky because Google has offered several variations of the integration plugins.  This one sample is 'pretty fresh' but setup for command-line build: https://github.com/stephen47/android-sdl2-gradle-template